# MessagePack C API

Tags: c, msgpack, messagepack

In looking at the C API for MessagePack, there are a number of functions to appropriately serialize (pack) the data according to type: `msgpack_pack_uint8`, `msgpack_pack_int32`, ...

There doesn't seem to be the equivalent call in the API to unpack the data.  `msgpack_unpack_next` returns a `msgpack_object`.  These objects only have coarse granularity of types (the largest of the type: int64, double, ...), based on the enums included.

Am I missing something here?  Is the expectation that the coarse object be used and then cast?

How should unpacking be done properly?

Furthermore, is there any good documentation or usage examples?  The ones on the website are trivial.

Comment: And where is the C API for MessagePack?

Comment: @sivann https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c or http://msgpack.org

Comment: thanks. I hoped there was more more analytical documentation.

Comment: The best documentation I can find is here: https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/wiki/v2_0_c_overview

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At unpack time, any integer value is always stored within a `msgpack_object` as a fixed-width 64-bit integer (`int64_t` if negative, `uint64_t` otherwise).

See `cpp/src/msgpack/object.h` for more details on `msgpack_object` et al., and `cpp/src/msgpack/unpack.c` to see how msgpack handles the unpacking logic, e.g.:

```
static inline int template_callback_int8(unpack_user* u,
                                         int8_t d,
                                         msgpack_object* o) {
    if(d >= 0) {
        o->type = MSGPACK_OBJECT_POSITIVE_INTEGER; o->via.u64 = d;
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        o->type = MSGPACK_OBJECT_NEGATIVE_INTEGER; o->via.i64 = d;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This is because at pack time, msgpack chooses dynamically the most optimal way to encode an integer according to its value, e.g. if you use `msgpack_pack_uint16` to pack your integer then:

- it will be saved in 1 byte if the value is in [0, 127],
- [2 bytes](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack/blob/master/spec.md#int-format-family) with `0xcc` as first byte if the value is in [128, 255],
- [3 bytes](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack/blob/master/spec.md#int-format-family) with `0xcd` as first byte otherwise.

See `msgpack_pack_real_uint16` from `cpp/src/msgpack/pack_template.h` for more details.

---

In other words at unpack time, msgpack uses a large enough positive or negative (test if `obj.type` is `MSGPACK_OBJECT_POSITIVE_INTEGER` or `MSGPACK_OBJECT_NEGATIVE_INTEGER`) to hold any integer value. So it's up to you to:

- cast if you can always assume that values will never overflow your cast type,
- or, check dynamically (with a mask) if the value is not large enough for your receiver type,
- or, always use an `int64_t` or `uint64_t`.

At last, the C test suite (`msgpack/cpp/test/msgpackc_test.cpp`) might be helpful to browse code samples.

Comment: Thanks!  I came to the same conclusion.  msgpack is efficient on the wire and it's up to you to know the protocol for appropriate conversions.  The cost of that efficiency is it can't automatically deduce the original type on unpacking.