# MessagePack unpack fails with large Metasploit Framework message in C received via Libcurl

Tags: c, libcurl, msgpack, metasploit

First off, I used [How do I unpack and extract data properly using msgpack-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393838/how-do-i-unpack-and-extract-data-properly-using-msgpack-c) to figure out how to properly unpack data since MessagePack's own C API documentation isn't great. Though, http://wiki.msgpack.org/display/MSGPACK/QuickStart+for+C+Language is okay too.

I would like to note that the code is working fine for most API calls to metasploit, it is only the big one (`module.exploits` about 16KB returned) that fails.

Like my last question, I'm at work so can't post the actual code. I will try to show accurately what my code is doing though in the following snippet.

```
// Function declaration from msgpack headers
bool msgpack_unpack_next(msgpack_unpacked* result, const char* data, size_t len, size_t* off);

// Called by curl after request
size_t unpack_result(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata){
    size_t real_size = size * nmemb;

    msgpack_unpacked msg;
    msgpack_unpacked_init(&msg);
    // Fails [returns false] when used on "module.exploits" return, not when
    // "module.payloads" is called nor "auth.login".
    msgpack_unpack_next(&msg, ptr, real_size, 0); 


}

msgpack_sbuffer* pack_payload(char **data, size_t size){
    // Code that actually packs payload, pretty standard with nothing special
    // Definitely works, have not had any problems with my payloads
}


int main(void)
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();

    char *auth_payload_array[3] = {"auth.login", "<username>", "<password>"};

    msgpack_sbuffer *auth_payload = pack_payload(auth_payload_array, 3);
    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://<IP Address>/api/");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, auth_payload->data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, auth_payload->size);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        // Add custom content type header
        struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: binary/message-pack");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, unpack_result);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if (res != CURLE_OK){
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                        curl_easy_strerror(res));
            return 1;
        }

        char *exploit_payload_array[2] = {"module.exploits", AUTH_TOKEN};
        msgpack_sbuffer *exploit_payload = pack_payload(exploit_payload_array,2);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, exploit_payload->data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, exploit_payload->size);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if (res != CURLE_OK){
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                        curl_easy_strerror(res));
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm aware that the above has memory leaks, I didn't feel like typing all the proper destroys/frees since this is just an example. I left out the part of how `AUTH_TOKEN` is actually grabbed since it shouldn't be the error, as I don't have problems at that point in the code. I also am aware some of the curl request code could be optimized into functions.

Important note is that the ruby gem works fine with this same API call, but it is a C extension that does not use the standard msgpack library, but does the binary parsing itself.

When I write the raw data from the return to a file instead of the stringbuffer examining it manually shows that it appears to be correct msgpack format.

Any ideas what is going wrong here? I'm going to start using gdb to try and track down the problem, along with looking into turning the ruby c extension into a library I can use since it seems to work. Hopefully though, it is something simple and one of you will catch it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The write callback doesn't return the correct return code.

Comment: Correct! I actually found this out independently just recently. To help possible googlers, the full explanation is my CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION function was not working correctly. The code was breaking when called multiple times, creating the issue. I wasn't logging properly when this code errored out, causing me to go down a rabbit hole looking for the issue :(.